Persist viewModel instance beetween fragments
My project at the moment is using Hilt for injection and supportFragmentManager for change fragments.
I im trying to get a shared viewModel between fragments, but only for 3 fragments for example.
Similar to using hiltNavGraphViewModels but without the Navigation component.
I have searched for a lot of information but I haven't found anything similar.
